# BlobRequestOptions in Azure.Storage.Blobs

Tags: azure, blob, storage

I have some blob access code written in C# that I need to move from using  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob to Azure.Storage.Blobs

In the old code, failover when reading blobs was handled with these lines of code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
Blob.BlobRequestOptions myBlobOptions = new Blob.BlobRequestOptions();
myBlobOptions.LocationMode = RetryPolicies.LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary;
myBlobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = myBlobOptions;
        
Blob.CloudBlobContainer myContainer = myBlobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
Blob.CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = myContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("blobfile");
```

What to do when using Azure.Storage.Blobs instead?

New Code:

```
BlobServiceClient BlobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("connectionString");
BlobContainerClient container = BlobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("container");
BlobClient blob = container.GetBlobClient("blobfile");
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and successfully read files in the azure blob storage through a piece of code.**

**Code:**

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;

namespace blobstr
{
    class program {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("< Connection string >");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient("sample1.csv");
            if (await blobClient.ExistsAsync())
            {
                var response = await blobClient.DownloadAsync();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Value.Content))
                {
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**Portal:**

*In Blob storage, I have a csv file with view in below snap.*

[image]

**Console:**

*After I executed the code in my console, I can read the file from azure blob storage successfully.*

[image]

Comment: I already know how to read blob-files, it's how to handle failover, as mentioned in the question, I used to use these lines to handle failover, but can find the same options in the  Azure.storage.Blobs:

Blob.BlobRequestOptions myBlobOptions = new Blob.BlobRequestOptions();
myBlobOptions.LocationMode = RetryPolicies.LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary;
myBlobClient.DefaultRequestOptions = myBlobOptions;